# arcpy.mapping use a template (mxd) to apply layout view?

Tags: arcpy, mxd, template

Is there a class or a function in `arcpy.mapping` that can import an empty mxd, that contains only the layout elements, and applying it?

Comment: For my project, i whould like to save an empty mxd as a template to apply it later to other mxd containing layers, so can't  use the switch

Comment: There is no function in arcpy to apply a layout from one mxd onto another.

Comment: There is no another way to apply the same layout elements to many mxd using python?